# Try to find the number of times an item appears in another list of list of string

Tags: python

I have this list of list of str and another search list *number*:

```
animal = [[['cat', 'cat', 'dog'], ['cat', 'cat', 'dog'], ['cat', 'cat', 'dog']]
number = ['cat', 'dog']
```

how do I make it on python so that it calculates the number of times each str inside number can be found in animal? for example, for 'cat' the answer would be 6 and for dog it would be 3. I tried to use the count method for list, but it works only if I have a str, I need it to search it using the list.

I tried to do a for loop (only for the first index):

```
found = 0
for char in animal:
    if str(number[0]) in str(animal):
        found = found+1
return found
```

the problem is that I cannot do that if I have an infinite number of str in number! If I have let's say 10 str in number I would have to do that loop for [0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],... which can take a lot of time.

Comment: Use nested loops?

Comment: Let's avoid use Python *built-in* *list* as the variable name.  See the post if you have any questions.  Try to think *reversing the search order* by start with *smaller* one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try this in simple form

```
list2 = ['cat', 'cat', 'dog']
number = ['cat', 'dog']


print([list2.count(j) for j in number])
```

output

```
[2, 1] #2 is times he find the first value 'cat' inside list2
```

using pandas library  without loops

```
list2 = ['cat', 'cat', 'dog']
number = ['cat', 'dog']
flatten_list = [['cat', 'cat', 'dog'], ['cat', 'cat', 'dog'], ['cat', 'cat', 'dog']]

import pandas as pd



from itertools import chain
def get(arr):
    
   if type(arr[0])==list:
       # if you have 2d array then make it 1d ex [[2],[4]] => [2,4]
       arr = list(chain.from_iterable(arr))
    

       counts = pd.Series(arr).value_counts() # return how many times the value repeated inside your array
       print(counts)# print result without loop

       # another way using loop same result
       print([arr.count(j) for j in number])

get(flatten_list) 
get(list2)
```

or with 2 for loop for 2d array

```
print([sum(i == item for a in flatten_list for i in a) for item in number])
```

output`[6,3]`

Comment: That's very inefficient - each *count* is O(n) - go through the whole list to find thing...

Comment: you can get value counts using pandas in list2 array in my code for example it return cat 2 and dog 1 without any loops

Comment: using your method, how would I be able to find my answer if list2 was a list of list of str? for example list2 = [['cat', 'cat', 'dog'], ['cat', 'cat', 'dog'], ['cat', 'cat', 'dog']] cat would be 6 and dog 3

Comment: There are two *loops* in this approach: one is explicit *for j in...* the other is implicit - *count()* .  If you understand how the *count* works....

Comment: @kfnwtfn you can flat the array if you not interesting of how many time in each row using this line of code """list2 = list(chain.from_iterable(list2))""" then apply same method

Comment: do you have like a simpler way of doing it? one that a beginner could understand?

Comment: @kfnwtfn I update the answer with some comment if any thing is not clear just mention it, the pandas method or the old method

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try this simple *Counter*:

```
from collections import Counter

L =  ['cat', 'cat', 'dog']
to_search = ['cat', 'dog']

counts = Counter(L)       # a dictionary - find item is O(1) 
print(counts)


for item in to_search:
    if item in counts:
        print(item, counts[item])
```

#### Output:

```
cat 2
dog 1
```

If you're only interested in search one single word/animal, you can just do this:

```
search_word  = 'cat'
print(counts[search_word])    # 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary:

```
animal = ['cat', 'cat', 'dog']
number = ['cat', 'dog']

counter_dict = dict()
for value in animal:
    #remove following 2 lines to count all unique values
    if value not in number: 
        continue #skip if not counting this value
    #get() function returns None if the key wasn't created yet
    #"or" part makes sure prev_count is number - None or 0 == 0
    prev_count = counter_dict.get(value) or 0
    counter_dict[value] = prev_count + 1
print(counter_dict)
```

Output: `{'cat': 2, 'dog': 1}`

Note: the "or" trick only works because I want 0 to be the default:
`None or x` returns `x`, but `0 or x` also returns `x`. Since `x` is `0` in this specific case, it doesn't make a difference.
It would be more proper to use

```
prev_count = counter_dict.get(value)
counter_dict[value] = 1 if prev_count is None else (prev_count + 1)
```

But that looks much less pretty